# Simple jq slider via position

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

guys!
 I have a problem with a simple js for simple slider. It works with position left: -=999px;
 my js change class for button to make it unactive, but button still works.
 where i miss? I need to disable the button ive click.

```js
$(function(){   
var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
$('a.control_next').click(function() {
  
  $('ol > li:first-child > a').removeClass('active');
  $('ol > li:last-child > a').removeClass('control_next');
  $('ol > li:first-child > a').addClass('control_prev');
  $('ol > li:last-child > a').addClass('active');
 
  $('#anim').animate({
    
    left: "-=920",
    
  }, 500, function() {
});
});

$('a.control_prev').click(function() {
  $('ol > li:last-child > a').removeClass('active');
  $('ol > li:last-child > a').addClass('control_next');
  $('ol > li:first-child > a').addClass('active');
  $('ol > li:first-child > a').removeClass('control_prev');

  $('#anim').animate({
    
    left: "+=920",
    
  }, 500, function() {
})
 
});

});
```

```css
#slider {
 overflow: hidden;
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
}
#slider ul {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1000%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}
#slider ul li {
 float: left;
 width: 920px;
 
}
ol{
 margin: 200px auto 0 auto;
 padding: 30px 20px;
 list-style: none;
 bottom: 0px;
 text-align: center;
}
ol > li {
 margin: 0 6px;
 display: inline-block;
}
ol > li > a{
 width: 11px;
 height: 11px;
 display: block;
 background: #f7f7f7;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 20px;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #a9afb3;
}
ol > li > a:hover:not(.active) {
 background: #333;
 -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}
ol > li > a.active{
 background: #a9afb3;
 cursor: default;
 -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
 transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider" class="block">
   <ul id="anim">
    <li><h2 class="twitter">AOS New York @aod</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit, sint! Accusamus rem molestias facilis, aliquid. Eum facere adipisci, minus ullam, quis quam eaque quia at recusandae vel veniam sint, veritatis.</p></li>
    <li><h2 class="twitter">AOS New York @aod</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit, sint! Accusamus rem molestias facilis, aliquid. Eum facere adipisci, minus ullam, quis quam eaque quia at recusandae vel veniam sint, veritatis.</p></li>
    
   </ul>
   <ol>
    <li><a class="control_prev active">&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li><a class="control_next">&nbsp;</a></li>
   </ol>
   
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using flags and setting them in each respective handler like

```js
$(function() {
  var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
  var next = true;
  var prev = false;
  $('a.control_next').click(function() {
    if (next) {
      $('ol > li:first-child > a').removeClass('active');
      $('ol > li:last-child > a').removeClass('control_next');
      $('ol > li:first-child > a').addClass('control_prev');
      $('ol > li:last-child > a').addClass('active');

      $('#anim').animate({

        left: "-=920",

      }, 500, function() {});
      next = false;
      prev = true;
    }

  });

  $('a.control_prev').click(function() {
    if (prev) {
      $('ol > li:last-child > a').removeClass('active');
      $('ol > li:last-child > a').addClass('control_next');
      $('ol > li:first-child > a').addClass('active');
      $('ol > li:first-child > a').removeClass('control_prev');

      $('#anim').animate({

        left: "+=920",

      }, 500, function() {})

    }
    next = true;
    prev = false;
  });

});
```

```css
#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
#slider ul {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1000%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}
#slider ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 920px;
}
ol {
  margin: 200px auto 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  list-style: none;
  bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
ol > li {
  margin: 0 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}
ol > li > a {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  display: block;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #a9afb3;
}
ol > li > a:hover:not(.active) {
  background: #333;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
  transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}
ol > li > a.active {
  background: #a9afb3;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
  transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider" class="block">
  <ul id="anim">
    <li>
      <h2 class="twitter">AOS New York @aod</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit, sint! Accusamus rem molestias facilis, aliquid. Eum facere adipisci, minus ullam, quis quam eaque quia at recusandae vel veniam sint, veritatis.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2 class="twitter">AOS New York @aod</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit, sint! Accusamus rem molestias facilis, aliquid. Eum facere adipisci, minus ullam, quis quam eaque quia at recusandae vel veniam sint, veritatis.</p>
    </li>

  </ul>
  <ol>
    <li><a class="control_prev active">&nbsp;</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="control_next">&nbsp;</a>
    </li>
  </ol>

</div>
```

Comment: i use a spike with   $('#anim').animate({

        left: "=0",

      }, 500, function() {})
just to back my slide :)
i dont understand why JS dont see changes in html with new classes

Comment: @RizShitname, Im not sure what you mean. Is this a problem or are you making a statement?